# Does the outcome of rolling a six-sided die satisfies the definition of a probability space?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I recently learned about the formal definition of a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$. But I feel like my grasp of it is a little shaky. I would like to understand this definition in the context of an example.

**Can someone demonstrate that the outcome of rolling a six-sided die satisfies the definition of a probability space?**

Note:

If I need to provide a specific definition of a probability space, tell me in a comment and I will go find one.

Comment: You should provide the definition, because while carefully writing out the definition, you may well see why the outcome of a die fits each requirement. And then you can think of how you could change things so that it would not fit the definition. This helps you get a grasp on the concept of probability space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a fair die then:

$\Omega:=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$

$\mathcal F:=\wp(\Omega)$

$P:\mathcal F\rightarrow[0,1]$ prescribed by $A\mapsto\frac16|A|$

---

**Addendum** to explain:

With this mathematical model we can describe and put calculations on the things that happen in the real world with the die. E.g. you can ask the question: what is the probability that an odd number is thrown? Answer: $P(\{1,3,5\})=\frac16|\{1,3,5\}|=\frac36=\frac12$.

I hope that this example makes clear to you that not only the singletons are the events here.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the $\sigma$  algebra part? I understand $\Omega$ and I understand $P$, but I don't follow $\mathcal{F}$. For starters, what does $p(\Omega)$ stand for? Power set? I assume $\mathcal{F}$ is non empty because it contains $1,2,3,4,5,6$. But for instance, why  is it closed under countable union? If I take $\lbrace 1\rbrace, \lbrace 2\rbrace$ then $\lbrace 1,2\rbrace$ isn't a member of $\Omega$ because I can't have both outcomes at once.

Comment: $\wp(\Omega)$ stands indeed for the powerset of $\Omega$ so *every* subset of $\Omega$ belongs to the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal F$. E.g. $\{1\}$ and $\{2\}$ are members of $\mathcal F$, and so is their union $\{1,2\}$. Also $\mathcal F$ is closed under complements as it should be. You are saying to assume that $\mathcal F$ contains $1,2,3,4,5,6$. That is not true. It contains $\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{4\},\{5\},\{6\}$ and also unions of these sets. Do not switch $\Omega$ (wich is not a $\sigma$-algebra) and $\mathcal F$. $\{1,2\}$ represents event: "throwing a $1$ or a $2$".

Comment: Ohhhhhh....wow. I didn't understand that at all. Specifically, I didn't realize the sigma algebra incorporated all the possibilities such as 1 *or* 2, 1 or 3, 1 or 2 or 3, etc were given taken into account. Okay now I understand everything I think. Thanks!

Comment: But why must we include all those extra combinations? Is $\lbrace 1, 2\rbrace$ considered an event? I thought the only events were $\lbrace 1\rbrace, \lbrace 2 \rbrace, \lbrace 3 \rbrace, \lbrace 4\rbrace, \lbrace 5\rbrace, \lbrace 6\rbrace$

Comment: My edit is an effort to make things more clear on this. Every subset of $\Omega$ is looked at as an event. Even $\emptyset$. It corresponds with "the die is thrown and no number appears". "This cannot happen.." is probably your first thought. In the model that thought is translated into $P(\emptyset)=0$.